# Cannot compile Visual Studio 2013 C++ project with enabled BullseyeCoverage and Casablanca REST SDK

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, casablanca, bullseye

I have Visual Studio 2013 C++ project which leverages Casablanca REST SDK features. Project compiles normally. I have enabled BullseyeCoverage Compile C++ 8.9.50 Windows License XXXX and error appeared in the project:

```
1>          D:\3rdparty\casablanca-2.4.0-r2\release\include\cpprest\astreambuf.h(404): error C2440: '?' : cannot convert from 'Concurrency::task<void>' to 'bool'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>          D:\3rdparty\casablanca-2.4.0-r2\release\include\cpprest\astreambuf.h(391) : while compiling class template member function 'Concurrency::task<void> Concurrency::streams::details::streambuf_state_manager<char>::close(std::ios_base::openmode)'
1>          d:\3rdparty\casablanca-2.4.0-r2\release\include\cpprest\containerstream.h(54) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Concurrency::streams::details::streambuf_state_manager<char>' being compiled
1>          d:\3rdparty\casablanca-2.4.0-r2\release\include\cpprest\containerstream.h(535) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Concurrency::streams::details::basic_container_buffer<_CollectionType>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _CollectionType=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>
1>          ]
1>          d:\3rdparty\casablanca-2.4.0-r2\release\include\cpprest\containerstream.h(533) : while compiling class template member function 'Concurrency::streams::container_buffer<_CollectionType>::container_buffer(_CollectionType,std::ios_base::openmode)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _CollectionType=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>
1>          ]
1>          d:\3rdparty\casablanca-2.4.0-r2\release\include\cpprest\containerstream.h(616) : see reference to function template instantiation 'Concurrency::streams::container_buffer<_CollectionType>::container_buffer(_CollectionType,std::ios_base::openmode)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _CollectionType=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>
1>          ]
1>          d:\3rdparty\casablanca-2.4.0-r2\release\include\cpprest\containerstream.h(616) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Concurrency::streams::container_buffer<_CollectionType>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _CollectionType=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>
1>          ]
1>          d:\3rdparty\casablanca-2.4.0-r2\release\include\cpprest\http_msg.h(491) : see reference to function template instantiation 'Concurrency::streams::istream Concurrency::streams::bytestream::open_istream<std::string>(_CollectionType)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _CollectionType=std::string
1>          ]
1>CL : error : status 2 from c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/CL.exe
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

When I disable bullseye coverage everything can be built normally. Any suggestions how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line:427 in astreambuf.h as following

```
 //closeOp = closeOp && _close_write().then([this_ptr]{}); 
   // passing down exceptions from closeOp
    closeOp = operator&&(closeOp, _close_write().then([this_ptr]{}));
```

Need to call the operator && explicitly, as the logic was override and bulls eye doesn't know how to handle it.